# How to style readonly attribute with CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm currently using readonly="readonly" to disable fields. I'm now trying to style the attribute using CSS. I've tried using

```
input[readonly] {
  /* styling info here */
}
```

but it is not working for some reason. I've also tried

```
input[readonly='readonly'] {
  /* styling info here */
}
```

that doesn't work either.

How can I style the readonly attribute with CSS?

Comment: `input[readonly]` should work. Make sure it's not being overridden by other, more specific selectors elsewhere in your stylesheet.

Comment: if you want to disable, then use the disabled attribute and not readonly

Comment: I noticed you miss an apostrophe in second selector. Should be input[readonly='readonly'] and it will work as well as input[readonly].

Comment: @SvenBieder Readonly and disabled have different behavior altogether. Readonly fields sent to the server on form submit while disabled fields are not.

Comment: `input[readonly='readonly']` will only work if you use HTML like `<input readonly="readonly">`, not for e.g. `<input readonly>`. `input[readonly]` should match both.

Comment: just an FYI, IE6/7 won't support this attribute selector- only IE8+

Comment: @Matt K: IE7 is fine with attribute selectors for stuff like `readonly`. It only messes up in some corner cases (e.g. getting DOM properties and HTML attributes mixed up).

Comment: @BoltClock: sorry, attached this comment to the wrong part. Curt's answer below won't work in IE6/7. it doesn't recognize `input[readonly="readonly"]`, it must be only `input[readonly]`.

Comment: @SvenBieder Yeah, I know it doesn't work the same as disabled. I have to use readonly because I want the form to submit the same values but prevent users from editing the field. I've used jQuery to prevent the readonly value from focusing so it's like disabled but you can submit values.

Comment: @vladsaling Sorry, that was a typo. I do have the apostrophe in the second selector. Have amended the question description.

Comment: @BoltClock I think this might be the reason. I use `class="setting"` to modify the settings fields in the form to make it different from the normal input value. I just tried using `!important` next to the readonly class in attempt prioritize the readonly class but it doesn't work. How else can I have both the settings class and readonly class present because only some fields are readonly and can't use readonly for all the fields.

Comment: `!important` should work to override, unless you also have `!important` on the setting class?

Comment: @Daphne oh, ok then :) what styles exactly your are trying to apply? not every input element support every css attribute...

Comment: @MattK Hmm, no I don't have `!important` on the settings class. My code is as follows:

`input[readonly] !important {  
 color: red;  
}  
input.setting {  
 font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
 font-size: 11px;  
 color: #676563;  
 background: #d5cec5;  
 border: 0px;  
 margin: 3px;  
 padding: 8px;  
 height: 18px;  
 width: 200px;  
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;  
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;  
}  
  
input:focus.setting {  
 color: #555;  
 background-color: #f5f1eb;  
}`

Comment: Could you edit that into your question, please? I also notice a stray `!important` after your selector - was that a mistake in your comment?

Comment: You can target attribute selectors in ie8 if the doctype is HTML5. caniuse.com

Answer (score 215):

```
input[readonly]
{
    background-color:blue;
}
```

https://curtistimson.co.uk/post/css/style-readonly-attribute-css/

Comment: You should use `input[readonly]` instead as `readonly` is a Boolean attribute that's not designed to have a specific value.

Comment: @BoltClock Yes. Please see the resolution in the Answer below.

Comment: How can I make it writeable again? Just removing the class style?

Comment: @RenaroSantos Thats a HTML change. Remove `readonly="readonly"` from your `input` element.

Comment: w/ IE7 you can still use the selector with jQuery

Comment: perhaps to fix the answer according to the @BoltClock's comment (for pleople that does not visit the link bellow)?

Comment: does not correspont to the snippet, but is better now ;)

Comment: finally, the answer is identical to the question! ;)

Comment: I have tried all the possible solutions and none of them work on iOS :( specifically I wanted to adjust the color property, that is by default a shade of light grey. edit to my previous comment, it actually works on iOS as well, but the color is dimmed a little bit, therefore the text color doesn't get the exact color set in CSS.

Answer (score 71):

Note that `textarea[readonly="readonly"]` works if you set `readonly="readonly"` in HTML but it does NOT work if you set the `readOnly`-attribute to `true` or `"readonly"` via JavaScript.

For the CSS selector to work **if you set `readOnly` with JavaScript** you have to use the selector `textarea[readonly]`.

Same behavior in Firefox 14 and Chrome 20.

To be on the safe side, i use both selectors.

```
textarea[readonly="readonly"], textarea[readonly] {
...
}
```

Comment: You may as well just use `textarea[readonly]` instead - every `textarea[readonly="readonly"]` is guaranteed to match that.

Answer (score 28):

Loads of answers here, but haven't seen the one I use:

```
input[type="text"]:read-only { color: blue; }
```

Note the dash in the pseudo selector. If the input is `readonly="false"` it'll catch that too since this selector catches the presence of readonly regardless of the value. Technically `false` is invalid according to specs, but the internet is not a perfect world. If you need to cover that case, you can do this:

```
input[type="text"]:read-only:not([read-only="false"]) { color: blue; }
```

`textarea` works the same way:

```
textarea:read-only:not([read-only="false"]) { color: blue; }
```

Keep in mind that html now supports not only `type="text"`, but a slew of other textual types such a `number`, `tel`, `email`, `date`, `time`, `url`, etc. Each would need to be added to the selector.

Comment: Neither do I. LOL Yes, you are correct! For now. `:read-only` and other psuedo selectors have been added to the W3C standard and can be used with IE 10 preview builds 10547 and higher.

Answer (score 22):

To be safe you may want to use both...

```
input[readonly], input[readonly="readonly"] {
    /*styling info here*/
}
```

The readonly attribute is a "boolean attribute", which can be either blank or "readonly" (the only valid values). http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#boolean-attribute

If you are using something like jQuery's `.prop('readonly', true)` function, you'll end up needing `[readonly]`, whereas if you are using `.attr("readonly", "readonly")` then you'll need `[readonly="readonly"]`.

---

**Correction:**
You only need to use `input[readonly]`. Including `input[readonly="readonly"]` is redundant. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19645203/1766230

Answer (score 7):

There are a few ways to do this.

The first is the most widely used. It works on all major browsers.

```
input[readonly] {
 background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

While the one above will select all inputs with `readonly` attached, this one below will select only what you desire. Make sure to replace `demo` with whatever input type you want.

```
input[type="demo"]:read-only {
 background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

This is an alternate to the first, but it's not used a whole lot:

```
input:read-only {
 background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

The `:read-only` selector is supported in Chrome, Opera, and Safari. Firefox uses `:-moz-read-only`. IE doesn't support the `:read-only` selector.

You can also use `input[readonly="readonly"]`, but this is pretty much the same as `input[readonly]`, from my experience.

Answer (score 4):

```
input[readonly], input:read-only {
    /* styling info here */
}
```

Shoud cover *all the cases* for a readonly input field...

Comment: input:read-only is the "mutability pseudo-class aiming at making form styling easier based on disabled, readonly and contenteditable HTML Attributes" As mentioned here, https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/r/read-write-read/, various implementations are quite wonky.

Comment: This is strange but only input[readonly] worked for me in FF 58

Answer (score 3):

capitalize the first letter of Only

```css
input[readOnly] {
      background: red !important;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" name="country" value="China" readonly="readonly" />
```

Answer (score 2):

If you select the input by the id and then add the `input[readonly="readonly"]` tag in the css, something like:

```
 #inputID input[readonly="readonly"] {
     background-color: #000000;
 }
```

That will not work. You have to select a parent class or id an then the input. Something like:

```
 .parentClass, #parentID input[readonly="readonly"] {
     background-color: #000000;
 }
```

My 2 cents while waiting for new tickets at work :D

Comment: "If you select the input by the id" – which the OP is not, so how is this relevant? Even if it was the case, you're wrong, you just need to remove the descendant combinator.

Comment: AH ok you mean i have to type something like input[readonly="readonly"]#inputID   ? /me fool.. you're right

Answer (score 1):

Use the following to work in all browsers:

```
 var readOnlyAttr = $('.textBoxClass').attr('readonly');
    if (typeof readOnlyAttr !== 'undefined' && readOnlyAttr !== false) {
        $('.textBoxClass').addClass('locked');
    }
```

Comment: So, hope your target audience is not in that 2%.

Comment: What include the class 'locked' ??

Comment: $('.textBoxClass').addClass('locked') will include 'locked'