# Can I select all elements with a specific class and set the readonly attribute to true in CSS

Tags: css, input, textbox, readonly

I have few text inputs and I want to make them readonly by CSS but not with :

```
readonly: "readonly" inlined
```

I checked this topic:

[How to style readonly attribute with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635293/how-to-style-readonly-attribute-with-css][1])

but it doesn't work for me.

I tried like this:

```
input.my-class[readonly]
{
}
```

and all of the variations of readonly="readonly" etc. but it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Can you show us the HTML code? there might be an alternative for what you are trying..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS cannot ***set*** any html attributes.

CSS can only ***style*** them.

Comment: It's in the name huh ;)?